# Howto add an element 2 associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

**my array**

```
$data1 = array(
        array(
                'title' => 'My title',
                'name' => 'My Name',
                'date' => 'My date'
        ),
        array(
                'title' => 'Another title',
                'name' => 'Another Name',
                'date' => 'Another date'
        )
);
```

I want to add one array   'status' => 1  all associative array :

```
$data = array(
        array(
                'title' => 'My title',
                'name' => 'My Name',
                'date' => 'My date',
                'status' => 1

        ),
        array(
                'title' => 'Another title',
                'name' => 'Another Name',
                'date' => 'Another date',
                'status' => 1
        ),
        array(
                'title' => 'second title',
                'name' => 'second Name',
                'date' => 'second date',
                'status' => 1
        )
);
```

Comment: You'd probably implement a [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and iterate over your outer array, or apply an [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) callback on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) wiil do the job:-

```
foreach($data1 as &$data){
   $data['status'] = 1;
}
print_r($data1);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/975058

***Reference:-***

[Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do but if you want to add the `status` flag to each of your items just try

```
foreach($data1 as &$item) {
   $item['status'] = 1;
}
```

This adds to every `$item` in `$data1` the new associative key `status` with value `1`

Answer (score 1):

The "Passing by reference" solution above is probably the most elegant one but if you don't want to modify your existing array, you can do it like this:

```
foreach ( $data1 as $value )
{
    $value["status"] = 1;
    $data[] = $value;
}

var_dump ( $data );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
  foreach($data as $key=>$val){
      $data[$key]['status'] = 1;
  }
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($data); 
?>
```

You can add status key in existing array.

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on StackOverflow because they do very little to educate.  Please edit your answer with the intent to educate the OP and thousands of future researchers regarding how your answer works and why it is a good technique.